# How can I use SSIS to map from an in place text value (in the source DB) to a FK table (in the dest DB)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have two databases.  My source looks like this:

```
FirstTable
------
TestingData
-----------
   Test
  Values
    go
   here
    go
   Test
```

I want to map to a database that looks like this:

```
FirstTable
------
TestingDataId
----------------
       1
       2
       3
       4
       3
       4

TestingDataEnum
------
TestingDataId      TestingDataValue
-------------      ----------------
     1                 Test
     2                Values
     3                  go
     4                 here
```

TestingDataId in table TestingDataEnum is the primary key, but it is not an identity.

The problem is that I need a way to insert the values only when they are new and convert them to the numeric value (either the newly inserted one, or the existing one).

I can seem some possible ways to hack this together, but I can't think I am the first one to want to abstract repeated data like this.  I would like to go with a proven solution rather than something that I just hack together.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this with SSIS?

Comment: @Siva - close.  I also need to insert new values into the TestingDataEnum.  (Though the more I think about it, I may have to handle this table manually.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the `Lookup` transformation to find the string and insert that in to the data flow. You can also use `Merge` to achieve the same thing but have a read of this SSIS Junkie article: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/10/21/2289.aspx

Alternatively, I'd recommend doing the lookup in the SQL providing the data (assuming the source data is coming from a database table as well).

**EDIT:** I missed the main point of your question with my initial answer, sorry, so I'll change it a bit. I thought you were only doing a lookup to change one data type to another but  the same can be used to find out if a value is not in your table.

When the lookup fails you need to handle the error and perform the `insert`, you should then be able to use the new `int` value in your data stream.

Or is that the "hack" method you were thinking of? :)

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  But it is good to know that I am not thinking it alone...